# Maths graduate expert in stats, optimization & numerical analysis - What should be my first step towards ML?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study

I'm a maths graduate and I have good statistics knowledge, optimization and numerical analysis (python mainly).

What should be my first step towards ML?
What should I first Learn now?

Comment: According to [this](http://drewconway.com/zia/2013/3/26/the-data-science-venn-diagram), you need some hacking skills.

Comment: @RichardHardy thank you. Where about would you suggest me ti start sito Hacking Skills?

Comment: "Hacking skills" is a jock term of saying programming. Learning R or Python (or any other language) is crucial because it allows one to apply analytical methods to real data; if you already know Python you are pretty covered. `sklearn` is easy to use. You are asking about ML: pick a subject of ML you are interested in (eg. [NLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) or [CV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_vision)) and read more on the subject. (In general it is somewhat unclear what you are asking...)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to familiarizing yourself with one of the widely used machine learning frameworks (e.g., tensorflow, pytorch, theano), I'd recommend reading an introductory book on machine learning. With your mathematical background, these should come easily to you, but they will give you an idea of the machine learning tools (and notational conventions) out there. Here are some suggestions:

Kevin Murphy, [**Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective**](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/MLbook/), 2012

As of this writing, still the newest comprehensive machine learning book out there. It covers a wide range of topics, including graphical models, some basics of deep learning, MCMC, and non-parametric models. Most chapters are fairly brief but given your mathematical background you might appreciate the conciseness. Great as a reference book.

Ian Goodfellow et al., [**Deep Learning**](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/), 2016/17

If you mainly want to learn about deep learning, choose this book. Given how fast the field moves, this is the only book in this list which can give you up-to-date knowledge on this topic.

Chris Bishop, [**Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning**](http://www.springer.com/gb/book/9780387310732), 2006

A bit older now, but still great as a gentle introduction to machine learning. Covers topics such as Bayesian statistics, maximum likelihood, linear models, backpropagation in neural networks, graphical models, expectation maximization, variational inference.

David Barber, [**Bayesian Reasoning and Machine Learning**](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.barber/brml/), 2010

If you fancy statistics, this book might be a good choice. No deep learning but lots of probabilities.

Comment: The Goodfellow book while nice has not yet passed the test of time. It might do but realistically Murphy's & Bishop's books are "classics" while the other suggestions are "very good to read". Probably the other classic missing is the "Elements of Statistical Learning" by Hastie et al.